# Show that the set $\{c_0,\dots,c_{N-1}\} \subset \mathbb{C}^N$ with vectors is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the set $\{c_0,\dots,c_{N-1}\} \subset \mathbb{C}^N$ with vectors $$c_j=\left(\frac{2}{N}\right)^\frac{1}{2}\left(1,\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi j}{N}\right),\dots,\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi j(N-1)}{N}\right)\right)$$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Is the same true of the set $\{s_0,\dots,s_{N-1}\} \subset \mathbb{C}^N$ with vecotrs $$s_j=\left(\frac{2}{N}\right)^\frac{1}{2}\left(1,\sin\left(\frac{2 \pi j}{N}\right),\dots,\sin\left(\frac{2 \pi j(N-1)}{N}\right)\right)?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint
$$
\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi jm}{N}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi km}{N}\right)=\frac12 \left(\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi (j+k)m}{N}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{2 \pi (j-k)m}{N}\right) \right)
$$
and
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\exp(\frac{2\pi i mk}{N}) = N\delta_{k,0}
$$

Comment: How am I suppose to use these hints? Can I get a starting hint?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown You're supposed to use the hints to facilitate the calculation of the inner products involved in checking orthonormality of your vectors.

Comment: Ok that is what I was thinking after researching similar problems, but I do not want to multiple N-2 vectors. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Show that the set $\{c_0,\dots,c_{N-1}\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^N$.}$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\langle c_j,c_k \rangle & = 1^2+\,cos(\frac{2\pi j}{N})\,cos(\frac{2\pi k}{N})+\dots+\,cos(\frac{2\pi j(N-1)}{N})\,cos(\frac{2\pi k(N-1)}{N}) \\
= & \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2}\,cos(\frac{2\pi j}{N}-\frac{2\pi k}{N}) +\frac{1}{2}\,cos(\frac{2\pi j}{N}+\frac{2\pi k}{N}) \\ 
& +\dots +\frac{1}{2}\,cos(\frac{2\pi j(N-1)}{N}-\frac{2\pi k(N-1)}{N}) +\frac{1}{2}\,cos(\frac{2\pi j(N-1)}{N}+\frac{2\pi k(N-1)}{N}) \\
= & \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2}\,cos(\frac{2\pi}{N}(j-k)) +\dots +\frac{1}{2}\,cos(\frac{2\pi (N-1)}{N}(j-k)) & (I) \\
& + \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2}\,cos(\frac{2\pi}{N}(j+k)) +\dots +\frac{1}{2}\,cos(\frac{2\pi (N-1)}{N}(j+k)) & (II) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Note we can write either (I) or (II) as $\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\,cos(\frac{2\pi i}{N})=0$ (*).

If $j \neq k$, by (*), $(I)+(II)=0$
If $j \neq k$, by (*), $(I)=c$, and $(II)=0$, so $(I)+(II)=0$.

$\textbf{Claim:}$ The set $\{s_0,\dots,s_{N-1}\} \subset \mathbb{C}^N$ isn't an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^N$.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Similar to the previous proof

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\langle s_j,s_k \rangle \\
= & \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2}\,sin(\frac{2\pi}{N}(j-k)) +\dots +\frac{1}{2}\,sin(\frac{2\pi (N-1)}{N}(j-k)) & (I) \\
& + \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2}\,sin(\frac{2\pi}{N}(j+k)) +\dots +\frac{1}{2}\,sin(\frac{2\pi (N-1)}{N}(j+k)) & (II) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Note we can write $$\frac{1}{2}\,sin(\frac{2\pi}{N}(j-k)) +\dots +\frac{1}{2}\,sin(\frac{2\pi (N-1)}{N}(j-k))=\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\,sin(\frac{2\pi i}{N})=0 (*)$$.

If $j \neq k$, by (*), $(I)+(II)=\frac{1}{2}+0+\frac{1}{2}+0=1$. So $\{s_0,\dots,s_{N-1}\}$ isn't an orthonormal basis.